# A Rare Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, knowledge

> My prefix is ironic.
>
> My infix is well-oiled.
>
> My suffix briefly handled a worm.
>
> There aren't many of me - what is my name?

---

*As usual, please include an explanation for each line in your final answer. The title is obliquely related to the final answer.*

Comment: Yay, this one made it longer than 7 minutes!

Comment: but not the 8th lol

Comment: @OmegaKrypton wait do you have the answer already o_O?

Comment: nah, i mean it didnt made the 8th minute with score=0 ;)

Comment: Could the downvoter _please_ explain the downvote? 3 questions in a row?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Possibly:

My prefix is ironic.

> FE (iron) as others have pointed out

My infix is well-oiled.

> E as in the logo for Enron, a "well-oiled" company

My infix is well-oiled - (second guess)

> E as in Euler's Number (pronounced oiler)

My suffix briefly handled a worm.

> EW - The exclamation made when touching a worm.  EW!

There aren't many of me - what is my name?

> FEW which also connects to the title (rare)

Comment: So close! I was thinking of something else for the infix. Think math.

Comment: Edited with new infix

Comment: You got it! Congratulations!

Answer (score 9):

Wild guess, but I’ll put it on here. The word is

> **FEWER**

My prefix is ironic.

> FE is the symbol for iron on the periodic table, as Omega Krypton indicated

My infix is well-oiled.

> Not sure about this one - maybe a reference to how a collective (WE) can act like a machine that’s well-oiled, or perhaps a wordplay clue?

My suffix briefly handled a worm.

> This one’s also stretch, but ERs - “emergency rooms” - have the ability to remove or at least mitigate the damage from worms that burrow inside the body

There aren't many of me - what is my name?

> If there aren’t many of something, there are FEWER of that thing

As for the title,

> having fewer of something would make it rarer to find

Comment: This is remarkably close. Infix is wordplay; I would probably add a knowledge tag for it and the prefix.

Answer (score 6):

Partial thoughts, havent come to an answer:

My prefix is ironic.

> Fe, chemical symbol of "iron"?

My infix is well-oiled.

> Lube for lubrication?

Comment: Don't want to confirm or deny yet :)

Comment: is that a hint? @Brandon_J

Comment: No. I'm not that clever lol.

Comment: could well-oiled be rot13(qehax) or something along those lines? Struggling to make a word with that in it though

Comment: @Smock true, thought of that too, but the OP said its wordplay, so... thanks nevertheless

Comment: Ah I see, perhaps something to do with an rot13(bvy jryy) then!?